# Divs won't center

Tags: css, layout, html, positioning

First of all [here's my code](http://jsfiddle.net/2yree/1/)

I'm having a lot of difficulty centering the "container" div and its children.
I've tried every type of positioning but i can't get it to stay centered after the browser is resized. 
I'm not sure where i'm going wrong and i've lurked the internet for hours to try and figure out why it's not positioning properly.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

- Don't center the `body` element.
- Center the outer div. It needs a specific width to be centered, with a width of 100% centering has no effect.
- Don't paste a complete web page in jsfiddle, it will wrap it in a page, so you will have duplicates of the page elements, making the markup invalid.

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/2yree/14/

Comment: I appreciate the advice. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/w4Wdy/

You just need to add:

```
#container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 620px;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work, because when you resize the window it repositions incorrectly. thanks very much for the info though!

Answer (score 0):

The `#container` element is 100% wide. How can you center something that is as wide as its parent? You can't.

Change the width so that the element fit inside as desired, yet has space on each side to actually center.

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/2yree/8/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the width for #container element, width: 100%; prevents the element from centering, you should change it to 50% or for example width: 300px;